# Functional Programming in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and going through the tutorial on the official website. It makes extensive use of classes. Each Component is a class unlike React's functional components. Is there anything similar in Angular?

Comment: Are you asking if [Angular](https://angular.io/) supports functional programming?

Comment: yes and also if its possible to use just plain JS in Angular 11 instead of TypeScript.

Comment: @Abra, I believe you have confused  _Functional Reactive Programming_ or simply _Reactive Programming_ with _Functional Programming_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No to both questions.

Angular is a somewhat strict framework and you need to follow it's rules, the components are implemented with classes and that is that, there's not way around that.

The same applies for Typescript, angular relies heavily on that, in particular with the decorators, there is not way it could work with plain JS.

You are also using the wrong term here (at least from an Angular point of view) there is something called Functional Programming, in VERY simple terms, it basically means that you avoid imperative code such as `for(let i=0; i< array.length; i++)` for a more functional approach such as `array.forEach`.

If you are interested you can read more about functional programming in Angular in this medium post: [Functional Programming in simple terms](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/functional-programming-in-simple-terms-abcef30a2ad1)

Comment: I would also like to add that React started with standard class components and functional components could be used for simpler elements. Now especially with the addition of hooks and for performance internal improvements I believe, they are trying to make functional components the standard (which I honestly do like). So basically I imagine that in the future react will kind of only have functional components and you can see class ones only in legacy code. So the functional components are kind of react's thing, as far as I can tell not even Vue has them.

Comment: yeah sorry for the long comment, I just wanted to mention that I believe that functional components are a rather specific react feature, so you should not really expect to see them much somewhere else.

Comment: About Typescript, that is just how Angular was build and it is an intrinsic part of the framework, but React and Vue also offer TS support. TS is getting more and more popular and widespread so I think you should not avoid it, but just take this opportunity to learn it as it will very likely come in handy to you in the future anyways :)

Comment: didn't you mean to write "imperative" instead of "declarative"?

Comment: Using a "for" loop is "not functional"? I thought functional programming just means you rely on (pure and immutable) functions for code reuse, instead of on classes and inheritance.

Comment: @ShacharHar-Shuv The definition of functional programming is in my opinion not totally defined and different people can have slightly different ideas of what it means, from my point of view I would definitely say that "for" loops are typical imperative operations whilst `forEach` used a functional approach. To give more context on the difference, please have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/functional-vs-imperative-programming#functional-programming-vs-imperative-programming

Comment: in my previous link I think the following sentence sums up the argument quite nicely: "With an imperative approach, a developer writes code that specifies the steps that the computer must take to accomplish the goal. This is sometimes referred to as algorithmic programming. In contrast, a functional approach involves composing the problem as a set of functions to be executed." (and in our case you can see that this indicates the difference in telling js to iterate via a for look vs the composition of the `forEach` function with its argument)

Comment: I just want to add that `.forEach` is often used as an example of a "functional approach". `forEach` is only good for side effects which means it is actually a very bad example as you're trying to isolate side effects and keep them in as few places as possible. The way better example is a for loop with Array.push vs a simple Array.map.

Answer (score 1):

There's a library in npm called `angular-function-component`. Although it's just a functional wrapping for a class component. And yes, Angular seems to have a mostly OOP approach.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-function-component

Answer (score 0):

I had worked with old AngularJS before, lately I got chance to visit the Angular again. By looking at their declaration of `Component`, functional programming probably isn't recommended.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'learn-angular';
}
```

The above is a class derived from base `Component`, but it's a class. This made me think that it won't support hooks either. I'm referring to the React hook instead of Service hooks.

Of course, the Javascript support of functional programming is still there, that has nothing to do with Angular, such as `arr.map`.